# Getting 401.0 on new web application

Tags: 2016, authentication

I created a new Web application using Central Admin in a farm with an existing, functional web app. The web app is pretty basic: blank host header, ssl, other settings using defaults.

After creating a site collection using the team site template, browsing the page gives a message of the server "is currently unable to handle this request". The SharePoint ULS log has "Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request '' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication." The IIS logs show 401.0. After turning off friendly http error messages, the page is simply blank.

I do not get prompted for authentication, and the behavior is the same when browsing from both the server and a client machine.

As far as I can tell, the new web app has the same authentication settings as the existing, working web apps. Any suggestions on where to look?

SharePoint 2016, on-prem.

Comment: Do you have a root web application under "/"?

Comment: A site collection? Yes.

Comment: clear your browser cache and grab a fiddler or F12 trace. Any redirects for auth in there at all? What are the auth settings for the webapp?

Comment: same issue from multiple browsers/machines. F12 shows one get request with a response of 500 / internal server error, with a content length of 0.

Comment: Please post screenshots of your AlternateAccessMappings and your IIS-Bindings from both WebApplications